# How to resolve 404 errors for wordpress comments/feed when I have disabled comments

Tags: comments, 404-error, feed

I have disabled comments in my wordpress site. So comments/feed url is giving 404 error. So how should I resolve these errors? doaminname/feed works fine. But domainname/comments/feed is giving error. So I want to fix that error.

Comment: You disabled comments and your ***feeds*** broke? I thought at first it was only your comments feed that didn't work but then you wrote "Other page name/feed is also giving 404 error" which implies that all of your feeds are broken. Can you clarify?

Comment: s_ha_dum I modified my question. I dont want solution for that other page. As It is already removed from the system. So it is giving 404 error.

Comment: I am having a very hard time breaking my feeds. I have been messing with comment settings and deleting comments for long enough to start wondering what you did. What did you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `remove_action( 'wp_head', 'feed_links', 2 );`  in functions.php file. and

added 
in the header.php.

This fulfilled my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to remove another hook. I had a plugin that was using it for event comments.

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3);
```